# How do I enable PUT requests in Azure?

Tags: php, iis, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm building a REST API on Azure, but when I try to access an endpoint via the PUT method I get a `HTTP 405 "Method Not Allowed"` status along with an IIS error message:

> The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid
>   method (HTTP verb) is being used.

**How do I enable the PUT method, and other methods that may be blocked by default by Azure's default config settings?**

I tried adding a web.config file to the root of my application with allowUnlisted set to true on the verbs element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <requestFiltering>
            <verbs applyToWebDAV="false" allowUnlisted="true" />
         </requestFiltering>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This changed nothing.

I'm an open source guy, so the world of IIS is very unfamiliar to me. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What language are you using? PHP, Node.js, ASP/ASP.NET or Python?

Comment: I'm using PHP (Laravel 4).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the following to the `web.config` in the `system.webServer` element:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="PHP54_via_FastCGI" />
  <add name="PHP54_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, LOCK, UNLOCK" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
</handlers>
```

This works for the built in versions of PHP, the current default is PHP 5.4, but if you have selected PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.5 you will need to modify the path of the php-cgi handler.

Comment: I've added these solutions to the Microsoft Azure Websites Cheatsheet.. http://microsoftazurewebsitescheatsheet.info

Comment: This worked! THANK YOU so much! I've been blocked by this for hours. I've bookmarked the cheatsheet, which is also incredibly helpful. Shame that MS doesn't allow HTTP method config in the portal, seems obvious enough.

Answer (score 6):

To complete the answer given by cory_flower you should change 54 by the version that is given,

Exemple: 7.2 gives:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="PHP72_via_FastCGI" />
  <add name="PHP72_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, LOCK, UNLOCK" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.2\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
</handlers>
```

Pretty trivial but just for info

**Update:** fixed path

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `web.config/system.webServer`:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0"
       path="*."
       verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,DELETE,PUT"
       type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
       preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

or instead of specifying what verbs are allowed, say `verb="*"` to allow all the verbs.

Comment: No, it wouldn't for PHP. That is for Asp.Net. But you never mentioned php in the question.