# Angular Put request not working with Laravel 5.3 hosted on azure

Tags: angularjs, azure-web-app-service, laravel-5.3, put

I am sending PUT request on my Laravel 5.3 application that is hosted on azure webapps. But I receive a delayed response *504 (Gateway Timeout)*. While It is working on POSTman (chrome extension).

this is my angular code:

```
put : function (id, params) {
  params.api_token = TOKEN;
  return $http.put(url+'/lead/'+id, params);
},
```

And running this would give me *504 (Gateway Timeout)* after 1 min

I have also setup *web.config* to handle PUT & DELETE. Described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170826/how-do-i-enable-put-requests-in-azure) in detail.

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="PHP54_via_FastCGI" />
    <add name="PHP54_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, LOCK, UNLOCK" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: Does [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/c5aa7b7b-59e6-4644-999f-b7f06eb79bb7/azure-http-504-gateway-timeout-wlong-requests) help you?

Comment: No, the issue is only with PUT requests, DELELTE requests are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Because Apache and IIS servers are different. IIS does not handle PUT and DELETE by default. It also handles params for PUT request differently.

Instead of body, you need to send it in a query string like `../resource?param1=value1`. AKA `x-www-form-urlencoded` [This article explains it thoroughly](http://techfunda.com/howto/573/http-put-server-request)

As of angular, this worked for me.

```
 function (id, params) {
        params.api_token = TOKEN;
        var params = $httpParamSerializerJQLike(params);
        return $http.put(url+'/lead/'+id+'?'+params);
    }
```

NOTE: In addition, your `web.config` does require `<handler>` tags to be able to handle these requests. which is defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170826/how-do-i-enable-put-requests-in-azure)