# Could not get POST to work on Azure Website

Tags: asp.net, web-services, rest, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an asp.net web application with REST Webservices which works fine on local, but when I upload it to Azure it does not work anymore... I'm doing a POSTasync, but I could see in my logfiles that GET is executed.

I've updated my web.config as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25171133/672756) and [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1891310.aspx?HTTP+405+Method+Not+Allowed) but it did not change anything.

Here is my MessageController:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging

Public Class Test
    Public Subject As String
    Public Body As String
End Class

Public Class MessagesController
    Inherits ApiController

    ' GET api/<controller>
    Public Function GetAllValues() As DataTable
    ...
    End Function
' POST api/<controller>
Public Function PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As Test) As HttpResponseMessage
...
End Function
```

I've also tried changed the Function PostValue to Sub PostValue without success.

My Global.asax looks like this:

```
Imports System.Web.SessionState
Imports System.Web.Http

Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:="DefaultApi", routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", defaults:=New With {
        Key .id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.[Optional]})
End Sub
```

If the GetAllValues exists, PostAsync calls the GetAllValues for whatever reason. If I delete the GetAllValues for testing, I get "Method not allowed".

Here is the method I use on my test aspx page to call the REST Webservice:

```
Private Async Sub PostTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PostTest.Click
    Dim m As New Test
    m.Subject = "Test"
    m.Body = "Testbody"

    Dim client As New Http.HttpClient

    Dim JsonData As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(m)
    Dim theContent As New Http.StringContent(JsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    Dim aResponse As Http.HttpResponseMessage = Await client.PostAsync("https://example.com/api/messages/", theContent)
```

**Update**
When I remove the GET method from my controller I get error message "MethodNotAllowed". Having a closer look at the returned content confuses me even more. The content is:

```
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}
```

But I'm using Await client.**Post**Async ....?

**Update 2**
I've also tried PostAsJsonAsync, but error is still that **'GET'** is not supported....

**Update 3**
I've now used [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and it seems that the POST itself works fine... With Fiddler Composer I could send POST to my azure https URL and the POST process is triggered as expected... Now I don't know why both client.PostAsync and client.PostAsJsonAsync seem to send a GET to the azure live url while the same code sends a POST on my localhost.... :-(

Comment: Just curious - what port is your app listening on?

Comment: It's included in my asp.net solution so port should be 443 as I use https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I've found the answer.... I had to remove the trailing slash! I've used "https://example.com/api/messages/" and this will automatically result in a GET, regardless whether I used PostAsync or PostAsJsonAsync.

With "https://example.com/api/messages" both GET and POST seem to work fine!!

Answer (score 0):

> I have an asp.net web application with REST Webservices which works fine on local, but when I upload it to Azure it does not work anymore

There might contain different IIS configurations between your development environment and Azure Web App. It seems that all the requests are treated as GET requests in server side.

You could add some configurations to Web.config to enable all the Verbs.  The configuration depends on the managed Pipeline mode. If the mode you choose on Azure Web App is Integrated, you could use following code.

```html
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"
       path="*."
       verb="*"
       type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
       preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

If the version you choose on Azure Web App is Classic, you could use following code.

```html
<handlers>
   <remove name="WebDAV" />
   <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
   <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"
      path="*."
      verb="*"
      modules="IsapiModule"
      scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"
      responseBufferLimit="0" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: Many thanks Amor! I had already tried both before, but without any changes. Now with Fiddler I've found the following: POST itself is working fine....? I sent a POST with Fiddler and my POST-Function is called as expected.... Now I don't know why client.PostAsync and client.PostAsJsonAsync should send a GET request....? So the problem seems to be in my aspx page sending the request, not in my REST service (or IIS / azure) receiving the request..... :-(