# PUT and DELETE 405 Method Not Allowed error in Laravel Web App hosted in Azure

Tags: laravel, azure

We are encountering 405 errors in my site for PUT and DELETE methods. It is a Laravel-React web app and it is hosted in Azure.

We already did the following:

- We followed this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397597/laravel-5-5-error-405-method-not-allowed-xhr-put-method-now-working-on-azure-s) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170826/how-do-i-enable-put-requests-in-azure/25171782#25171782)
- Removed webdav
- Updated node and npm
- made sure laravel is up to date

We already scraped off a lot of the questions here in Stackoverflow and other sites. We still couldn't figure out why the 405 error still appears. All methods were working in our localhost but when we tried to deploy it to Azure, that's when the errors appeared.