# How to enable PUT and DELETE requests on Azure?

Tags: php, laravel, azure, put, azure-web-app-service

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and PHP 7.1 running in an AppService, POST and GET works correctly but when I call a route with PUT or DELETE the application response with a status **405 Method Not Allowed**, I've added in my web.config the next lines:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With,Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT,PATCH" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
<handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="PHP71_via_FastCGI" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS,XYZ" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS,XYZ" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS,XYZ" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    <add name="PHP71_via_FastCGI" path="*" verb="GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, LOCK, UNLOCK" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.1\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
</handlers>
```

But it still does not work.

Comment: Here is a similar thread , Please apply the same setting and restart your app in azure and try again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170826/how-do-i-enable-put-requests-in-azure