# Laravel: Getting a 405 on Azure for DELETE requests via Axios

Tags: laravel, azure

I've been working on a Laravel project for some time now and unfortunately hit a snag with sending a DELETE request on the production version hosted on Microsoft Azure. I found out the issue was that Azure by default denies DELETE requests to which I was directed to: [How do I enable PUT requests in Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170826/how-do-i-enable-put-requests-in-azure). However, I've updated the web.config file to the following: (Server PHP version 7.3, 64-bit)

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="PHP73_via_FastCGI" />
      <add name="PHP73_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, LOCK, UNLOCK, DELETE" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files\PHP\v7.3\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I had previously tried to run this accessing `D:\Program Files (x86)` but unfortunately that hasn't worked either. I've posted the entire web.config because I'm not sure if some of the other settings that have been added conflict with trying to enable the DELETE.

For reference here's the route that is called:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function($router) {
    Route::post('likes', 'LikesController@store');
    Route::delete('likes/{', 'LikesController@remove');
    Route::delete('likes/{like}', 'LikesController@remove');
});
```

The call to `LikesController@remove` only runs `$like->delete();` and then returns the comment without the like that has been deleted.

Method inside of the view component that calls axios:

```
axios.post('/api/likes', {comment_id: this.comment.id}).then((response) => {
  this.comment = response.data;
}
```

I have this working fine on my local build so I'm unsure of why the issue is persisting beyond the fix that has been provided. If there's anything else that is needed please let me know and I will edit the post.

Comment: Did you try restarting the server after updating your config?

Comment: The server gets restarted every time it gets deployed, if it isn't the register and login pages via `php artisan make:auth` come back with a 404 and unfortunately the issue still persists